# Orders table structure, mysql

Tags: mysql, structure

Just simple question - how to organize an orders' table, i.e. when somebody orders 2x item with id=1 and 3x item with id=2.

My previous solution were to save it like: `2x1,3x2` in `products` column, and then explode() it, but it's very inefficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go with 3 tables :

- The `product` table -- which is quite independant from the ordering system, and is used by the website to just display products
- An `order` table, which stores the basic informations of an order *(like who ordered, the billing address, ...)*
- And a `order_product` join-table between those two, indcating, for each order, which products it contains, and in which quantity.

That last table would contain, at least, the following fields :

- `id_order` : identifier of the order
- `id_production` : identifier of the product
- `quantity` : number of times this product has been bought in this order

Comment: It seems to be the most convenient solution. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :-) *(it's not only the most convenient solution, but also the one that allows you to query your data without having any kind of explode)*

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proposal, a bit more expanded:

**customers table:**

```
id
name 
email
timestamps  (created, modified, deleted)
```

**customer_addresses:**

```
id
customer_id
street
zip_code
city
state
country
type (enum or varchar indexed  - options would be 'billing', 'shipping')
```

**orders:**

```
id
customer_id
subtotal (without taxes, discount, shipping, etc.)
total (including additional order line items)
billing_address_id (foreign key from customer_addresses) 
shipping_address_id (foreign key from customer_addresses) 
status (paid, checkout, canceled, failed, expired...)
payment type
timestamps (created, modified, deleted)
```

**order_items**:

```
id
order_id
item_id
item_quantity
price
```

**order_line_items ( optional, where would be stored additional costs like shipping, discount, tax, etc):**

```
id
order_id
type
amount
timestamps
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the accepted answer is very good, but I would extend it with a `customers` table, also.

Here is a fuller example of the structure I am planning to use for my project (not tested yet)...

```
CUSTOMERS table:
    _id
    name
    address
    tel
    email

PRODUCTS table:
    _id
    name
    price

ORDERS table:
    _id
    customer_id
    datetime

ORDER_PRODUCTS table:
    _id
    order_id
    product_id
    product_quantity
```

...so, basically, if a customer has 3 different products (e.g., 1 apple, 2 bananas and 4 hats) in his order, then we would see 1 row being added to the `ORDERS` table and 3 rows being added to the `ORDER_PRODUCTS` table.

Comment: Price should be associated to Order too, so if you change the product price in the future you still can see the old products prices